# Python loading image into memory (numpy arrays) from database bytes field fast

Tags: python, numpy, image

I am looking for feedback on the function below to load a png image stored as bytes from a MongoDB into numpy arrays.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def bytes_to_matricies(image_bytes):
    """image bytes into Pillow image object
    image_bytes: image bytes accessed from Mongodb
    """

    raw_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
    greyscale_matrix = np.array(raw_image.convert("L"))
    color_matrix = np.array(raw_image.convert("RGB"))

    n = greyscale_matrix.shape[0]
    m = greyscale_matrix.shape[1]
    return greyscale_matrix, color_matrix, n, m
```

I have profiled my code with cProfile and found this function to be a big bottleneck. Any way to optimise it would be great. Note, I have compiled most of the project with Cython, which is why you'll see .pyx files. This hasn't affected much.

```
   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       72  331.537    4.605  338.226    4.698 cleaner.pyx:154(clean_image)
        1  139.401  139.401  139.401  139.401 {built-in method builtins.input}
      356   31.144    0.087   31.144    0.087 {method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}
    11253   15.421    0.001   15.421    0.001 {method 'encode' of 'ImagingEncoder' objects}
      706   10.561    0.015   10.561    0.015 {method 'decode' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
       72    5.044    0.070    5.047    0.070 {built-in method scipy.ndimage._ni_label._label}
     7853    0.881    0.000    0.881    0.000 cleaner.pyx:216(is_period)
       72    0.844    0.012    1.266    0.018 cleaner.pyx:349(get_binarized_matrix)
       72    0.802    0.011    0.802    0.011 {method 'convert' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
       72    0.786    0.011   13.167    0.183 cleaner.pyx:57(bytes_to_matricies)
```

If you are wondering how the images are encoded before being written into the MongoDB here is that code:

```
def get_encoded_image(filename: str):
    """Binary encodes image.
    """
    image = filesystem_io.read_as_pillow(filename) # Just reads file on disk into PILLOW Image object
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(stream, format='PNG')

    encoded_string = stream.getvalue()
    return encoded_string  # This will be written to MongoDB
```

Things I have tried:

1. As mentioned above I tried compiling with Cython
2. I have tried to use the lycon library but could not see how to load from bytes.
3. I have tried using Pillow SIMD. It made things slower.
4. I am able to use multiprocessing. But I want to optimise the function before I parallalize it.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Answer to questions from Reinderein: The images are photographs of documents. They will eventually be OCR'd. I'm not sure how a lossy compression would affect the OCR quality. DPI is 320. Size on disk ~ 800kb each.

Comment: What is the nature of your input image - size in DB, pixel dimensions, content? Is it something like a graph (lots of continuous colour regions) or a photograph? What is the reason to encode it in PNG? Does your image strictly need to be lossless?

Comment: @Reinderien I have updated the question with answers to the above.

Comment: One improvement opportunity, I see is to use YCbCr format  rather than RGB. It will save you cost of conversion to grey because Y channel can directly give you grey image.

Comment: I removed my previous answer because the results were misleading. After running your code step by step using the [codetiming](https://realpython.com/python-timer/) lib it seems that the bottleneck lies in the grayscale conversion (`raw_image.convert("L")`). But I believe that test is itself misleading - it is as if subsequent calls to .convert in Pillow were benefiting from some sort of cache. It's also possible the picture I used does not yield representative results. Numpy might be used for grayscale conversion instead of PIL - see: https://e2eml.school/convert_rgb_to_grayscale.html

Comment: @Neil for us to test your code (as you have it), we would need some example images. Do you have the code plus sample images, perhaps on github? After we have that, we can run tests in an attempt to optimise. If the images are confidential, see if you can find others similar in form.